# Set background image React

Tags: reactjs

I know there are many questions similar to this, I have read almost all of them, but in spite of this I cannot set an image as a background for my home page.
I also tried using the templates provided by bootstrap or other sites, but I could not get any results in this regard.
Is it possible to set the background without working on the CSS file?

This is the Home page code.

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <div>

      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <div class="card-header"><div>Iframe AdEx</div>
            <div >
              <button
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: "0",
                  right: "0",
                  left: "1000"
                }}
                class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle "
                type="button"
                id="dropdownMenuButton"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Link AdSlot
        </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/336x280/">336x280</Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/336x280-b">336x280-b</Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/300x100">300x100</Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/300x250">300x250</Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/160x600">160x600</Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/180x150">180x150</Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/180x150-b">180x150-b</Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/234x60">234x60</Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/234x60-b">234x60-b</Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  href="#"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/468x60">468x60</Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  class="dropdown-item"
                  onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                >
                  <Link to="/250x250">250x250</Link>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                <th scope="col">Link</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Trigger Pubblicità</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                    onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                  >
                    <Link to="/pubblicità">Trigger Pubblicità</Link>
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Pubblicità Automatica</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                    onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                  >
                    <Link to="/pubblicitàautomatica">
                      Pubblicità Automatica
                    </Link>
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Simulatore TV</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                    onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                  >
                    <Link to="/simulatoretv">Simulatore TV</Link>
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">4</th>
                <td>Piattaforma OTT</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                    onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                  >
                    <Link to="/piattaformaott">Piattaforma OTT</Link>
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">5</th>
                <td>Piattaforma Automatica</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-outline-primary"
                    onClick={() => window.location.reload()}
                  >
                    <Link to="/piattaformaautomatica">
                      Piattaforma Automatica
                    </Link>
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

Thanks a lot to those who will have the patience to help me.

Comment: just use style property: `style={{backgroundImage:`url(${Background})`;}}`

Comment: if the image is in the same folder as the Home Page component, and is named "Background.jpg", should i do this?


const Home = () => (

  <div style={{backgroundImage:url(${Background});}} >

    <div>


      <BrowserRouter>


        <div>

Comment: first you need to import it `import Background from '.Background.jpg';`

Answer (score 0):

```
var backgroundStyle = {
    width: "100%",
    height: "400px",
    backgroundImage: "url(https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png)"
};

<div style={backgroundStyle}>
```

Try this.